# Conditional Formatting Custom Formula in Excel based on percentage limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to build a conditional formatting custom formula in Excel for this use case.

1. The custom formula to be applied to the 'Current' column
2. If the value in the 'Current' column is greater than (10% lower value in the High column) then the font will appear Green.
   e.g. for the 1st record [High: 199] any value greater than [199 - 10%] = 179 will appear Green.
3. Same if the value in the 'Current' column is lesser than (10% upper value in the Low column) then the font will appear Red.
   e.g. for the 2nd record [Low: 702] any value lesser than [702 + 10%] = 772 will appear Red.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPs3A.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and explain how it fails to achieve the desired result?

Comment: For Green: `=B2*(1-10%)<A2` use this formula in CF and set the custom formatting as `[Color10] 0.00` while for Red: `=A2<C2*(1+10%)` and set the cf as `[Red] 0.00` lmk if that works or not

Comment: @BishalBasak do you want me to post it as an answer?